# Detect limit switch reached

Tags: labview

I'm having a little bit of a problem with LabVIEW 6.x concerning the motion control stuff. How do I detect whether a limit switch has been reached? So far I haven't found a way to do that. So what I'm trying to do is detect the minimum and maximum position of the attached device. To do that, I initiate a movement by using "Load Target Position" und "Start Movement" (don't recall the exact name of the latter). Now, if the position reaches a limit, the movement stops. But how do I detect that it stopped because the physical limit has been reached? I tried using the error output, but it just tells me that there is no error, although it displays a message box telling me that the limit in the direction of travel has been reached. It also tells me that this is warning 70026. But that number doesn't appear anywhere else, particularly not in the error code where I expected it to be. So I hope I made clear what I'm trying to accomplish and am grateful for any help on that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add the device that you're using, and which software you use (esp. Motion driver version). Given that LV 6 is rather old (2000) is it possible for you to upgrade?

Comment: It's a Steinmeyer OFD device with 4 axes on a 7344 controller. (Where can I find the driver version?) I made a screenshot of the SubVI that I use: http://unicornteam.de/image-bin/Find-limits-2.png At least it finds the positions most of the time. But sometimes the device goes crazy and sticks to one end and kind of thrusts against it over and over. I guess I'm doing something terribly wrong, but I can't figure out how to do this properly. I call this SubVI twice, with directions 1 and -1, to find both ends. Unfortunately, an upgrade to a newer version is not option.

Comment: We had an issue one time where the power lines (DC voltages), were running in the same cable as the communication cables, it's wise for you to check those and ground the shielding correctly.

Comment: The nature of the problem seems to have changed suddenly, because I just found out that the limit switches are not active. I'm almost certain they were before, but I could be wrong. Now, how do I activate them? In MAX under "Devices and Interfaces -> PCI-7344 -> Board2 X1 -> Axis Settings -> Limit Switches" both are set to "enabled", but under "1-D Interactive -> Axis Status -> Limit Switch" there is no green light. Querying the status programatically also returns false. I tried "Enable Limits.flx" and set all inputs to true, but nothing changed.

Comment: Enabled and Active are two different things (I think), the Enabled means that the device has limit switches and uses them, while Active seems to mean that they are triggered (or tripped).

Comment: You are perfectly right, Ton! "Active" is indeed the information that tells me whether a limit switch has been triggered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness sake:
Your looking into the wrong property, 'enabled' means that the device  is equipped with a limit switch and 'listening' to it.
Active means that the limit switch is triggered.